# Перенос значений из списка в другой список

Tags: python

Есть 3 списка, 2 из которых пустые, один заполнен значениями. По ходу работы программы нужно из заполненого списка переносить строки в два других в зависимости от событий. Не могу понять как это сделать.

Comment: `b[0] = a[0]`, `c[0] = a[1]` или `.append(a[idx])`

Comment: "переносить строки в два других"... непонятно... добавьте пример?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = []
b = []
c = list(range(20))
event = True
for element in c:
    # event = любое логическое выражение, например element % 2 == 0 (element - чётное число)
    event = element % 2 == 0
    if event:
        a.append(element)
    else:
        b.append(element)


print("Первый массив:", *a)
print("Второй массив:", *b)
```

Comment: вы телепат?.. или однокласник Nazzzar-а? )

Comment: @Jack_oS Если бы, просто мимо проходил